# SwiftUI onTapGesture displays new view

Tags: view, swiftui

I am using SwiftUI to make my own Pizza delivery application. I am now stuck cause I do not know how I could display the same image view (including a pizza's description) related to his own index from the array.  Instead of the lines `{self.images print("ok")}`, I would like that each time the user tap on an image from the array it displays the same image with a short text description. Is the description of my issue clear enough? I would be extremely grateful if anyone could help me out with this. Thanks a lot for reading it. This is the code:

```
HStack {
    ForEach(images, id: \.id) { post in
        ForEach(0..<1) { _ in
            ImageView(postImages: post)
        }
    }
    Spacer()
}
.onTapGesture {
    self.images
    print("ok")
}
.navigationBarTitle("Choose your Pizza")
.padding()
```

Comment: Your issue is not clear enough - how do you want your new view to be displayed? As a sheet, with a navigation link...?

Comment: When the ".onTapGesture" is triggered I would like that each image from the array display the same image on the exact same page. I do know that I will have to use a "location property" but I don't know how. Please any help? 

Comment: So you have an array of images (with no descriptions at the beginning) and when the user taps a specific image you want to show this image with its description - or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I would like to do! Any idea, please?

Comment: And do you want it to be displayed as a new window *on top* of the existing array of images? Or just add a single description line to the selected image?

Comment: Yes I would like it o be displayed as a new window on top of the existing array of images. Thanks a lot for trying to help me out by the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have a struct for your `Item`, you need to conform it to `Identifiable`:

```
struct Item: Identifiable {
    var id: String { name } // needed for `Identifiable`

    let name: String
    let imageName: String
    let description: String
}
```

Then in your main view:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    let items = [
        Item(name: "item1", imageName: "circle", description: "some description of item 1"),
        Item(name: "item2", imageName: "circle", description: "some description of item 2"),
        Item(name: "item3", imageName: "circle", description: "some description of item 3"),
    ]

    @State var selectedItem: Item? // <- track the selected item

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            HStack {
                ForEach(items, id: \.id) { item in
                    ImageView(imageName: item.imageName)
                        .onTapGesture { 
                            self.selectedItem = item // select the tapped item
                        }
                }
                Spacer()
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Choose your Pizza")
            .padding()
        }
        .sheet(item: $selectedItem) { item in // show a new sheet if selectedItem is not `nil`
            DetailView(item: item)
        }
    }
}
```

If you have a custom view for your image:

```
struct ImageView: View {
    let imageName: String

    var body: some View {
        Image(systemName: imageName)
    }
}
```

you can create a detailed view for your item (with item description etc):

```
struct DetailView: View {
    let item: Item

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(item.name)
            Image(systemName: item.imageName)
            Text(item.description)
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

Here is a different approach using the same View to display an image or an image with its description:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var items = [
        Item(name: "item1", imageName: "circle", description: "some description of item 1"),
        Item(name: "item2", imageName: "circle", description: "some description of item 2"),
        Item(name: "item3", imageName: "circle", description: "some description of item 3"),
    ]

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            HStack {
                ForEach(items, id: \.self) { item in
                    DetailView(item: item)
                }
                Spacer()
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Choose your Pizza")
            .padding()
        }
    }
}
```

```
struct DetailView: View {
    @State var showDescription = false
    let item: Item

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(item.name)
            Image(systemName: item.imageName)
            if showDescription {
                Text(item.description)
            }
        }
        .onTapGesture {
            self.showDescription.toggle()
        }
    }
}
```

and conform `Item`  to `Hashable`:

```
struct Item: Hashable
```

or instead of:

```
ForEach(items, id: \.self)
```

specify the `id` explicitly:

```
ForEach(items, id: \.name)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your contribution! Unfortunately, that is not quite what I would like to do.

Comment: Cause once the image is tapped, I do not what that is opened a new window. I want that it displays the same image (related to its own index of the array) in the exact same page with a short text description. So basically, I do know that I have to use a "location property" in the "onTapGesture" bracket. But thank you a lot anyway for answering.

Comment: @Momo I believe you said *I would like it to be displayed as a new window on top of the existing array of images.* Anyway I've added another solution.

Comment: Unfortunately, I know get this issue "Referencing initializer 'init(_:id:content:)' on 'ForEach' requires that 'Item' conform to 'Hashable' "

Comment: @Momo Yes, I forgot to add it to the answer - see updated.

Comment: Unfortunately, it hasn't worked. I've tried to adapt the lines  code you gave me but I still get an error.

Comment: @Momo I suggest you copy my code to the playground and see how it works. What error are you getting?

Comment: Thank you so much. I'm so grateful to you for helping me out with this :). I've almost done it.

Answer (score 2):

I also took a stab at it, for what it's worth.

(BTW @pawello2222's answer is also 100% correct. There is more than one way to achieve what you described)

I first created a pizza menu (using placeholder images):

[Main pizza list view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kRUZF.png)

Upon selecting an item from the menu, you are taken to the chosen pizza detail:

[Chosen pizza detail view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Grw2e.png)

I'm using `NavigationView` and `NavigationLink` to navigate between views.

Here's the full source code (for best results run in Swift Playgrounds):

```swift
import PlaygroundSupport // For running in Swift Playground only
import SwiftUI

// The main pizza listing page (view)
struct PizzaList: View {
    
    // Array of pizza images
    let pizzaImages = [
        Image(systemName: "circle.fill"),
        Image(systemName: "square.fill"),
        Image(systemName: "triangle.fill")
    ]
    
    // Array of pizza descriptions
    let pizzaDescriptions = [
        "Circular Pizza",
        "Square Pizza",
        "Triangle Pizza"
    ]
    
    var body: some View {
        // Wrap in navigation view to be able to switch between "pages"
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                ForEach(0 ..< pizzaImages.count) { index in
                    // Wrap in navigation link to provide a link to the next "page"
                    NavigationLink(
                        // This is the contents of the chosen pizza page
                        destination: PizzaDetail(
                            pizzaImage: self.pizzaImages[index],
                            description: self.pizzaDescriptions[index]
                        )
                    ) {
                        // This is an item on the main list
                        PizzaRow(
                            pizzaImage: self.pizzaImages[index],
                            description: self.pizzaDescriptions[index]
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Available Pizzas")
        }
        .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
    }
}

// Layout for each pizza item on the list
struct PizzaRow: View {
    
    let pizzaImage: Image
    let description: String
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Spacer()
            
            pizzaImage
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                .foregroundColor(.orange)
            Spacer()
            
            Text(self.description)
            Spacer()
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

// Layout for the chosen pizza page
struct PizzaDetail: View {
    
    let pizzaImage: Image
    let description: String
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Spacer()
            Text(description)
                .font(.title)
            
            Spacer()
            
            pizzaImage
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
            Spacer()
        }
        .padding()
        .navigationBarTitle("Your Pizza Choice")
    }
}

// For Playgrounds only
PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(PizzaList())
```

Comment: Instead of two separate arrays (pizzaImages, pizzaDescriptions) it might be better to create a struct holding everything together. With separate arrays, dealing with indices is risky - you may easily forget to add a description when adding a new image. And you're checking only the `pizzaImages.count` - what if `pizzaDescriptions.count` is smaller?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your contribution. Thank you so much for your contribution! Unfortunately, that is not quite what I would like to do. Cause once the image is tapped, I do not what that is opened a new window. I want that it displays the same image (related to its own index of the array) in the exact same page with a short text description. So basically, I do know that I have to use a "location property" in the "onTapGesture" bracket. But thank you a lot anyway for answering.